# Blocking the entire site excepting one folder with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to Apache and htaccess.

I want to allow only one IP to see the entire site, but for the rest of the people to have all files returning 403 except one folder and his files.

I already tried this and it's working only for the index, and not for all the files from the folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"/freedom"$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# allow one IP access everything
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if request is not for /freedom/... then return 403 
RewriteRule !^freedom(/.*)?$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Great response, worked for every page in /freedom, but I didn't mean to allow even the index of the main page, only the /freedom index

Comment: Thank you so much !